# Backup Databases and Users while Reinstall Wamp

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

Is there some easier way to backup all databases and users and permissions etc in WAMP than to do each one manually via phpmyadmin. Apache is using a lot of CPU ( rather it jumps around a lot even when nothing is happening that I'm aware of ) so I would like to just uninstall it and reinstall.

I have about 10-15 databases each with it's own user and I want to keep most of them. ( unless that many databases is the cause of the problem in the first place, but I'd be surprised at that ).

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: @bksi preferably some way I could export all the DB's together, but more importantly some way of exporting the users ( is this even possible or would I have to write each user down manually and re set it up again )

Comment: Tou can easly export via PHPMYAdmin all dbs. User priviledges are stored in system tables of mysql

Comment: @bksi thanks ... do you want to detail this a bit in an answer. How would the user priv backup and restore work exactly - not sure where the system tables are ... having a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From home page on phpmyadmin you can export all dbs, just click on tab export. The users are stored on Mysql DB table users

I suggest to chose only your dbs to export instead export all of them, because you will get troubles if you try to import system mysql dbs back via phpmyadmin

table users is stored in "mysql" db.
user privileges are stored within table "USER_PRIVILEGES" in information_schema db
and table "db" in "mysql" db

You should login as root to see system databases.

When export system tables use custom method, and on "Function to use when dumping data" dropdown use "REPLACE" instead "INSERT"

Comment: thanks ... where's the `Mysql` DB table though ... do you mean `information_schema`

Comment: I dont see any mysql db though

Comment: right I see the table user_priveleges ... how would i backup and restore this then?

Comment: Same way you backup databases. open this table and click on export tab

Comment: use custom export and use "replace" method instead "insert"

Comment: ok but how do i restore it ... I thought you said it was a bad idea "try to import system mysql dbs back via phpmyadmin"

Comment: it is bad idea to try to import directly all system db

Comment: but you can import those tables without problem, just use "replace" method in this export instead "insert"

Comment: ok - i see - can you just clarify which tables though ... I find your answer a bit confusing because you say ""USER_PRIVILEGES" in information_schema db and table "db" in "mysql" db" ... I only have information_schema ... i don't have a database called "mysql" at all that I can see. is it the same table ( will either work or do I need both )

Comment: no. you have to have those 2 databases. they are system databases.

Comment: oh dear you're right ... sorry ... wasn't looking properly ... thanks ... do i need to import BOTH those tables then, yes?

Comment: you have to export those 3 tables to have all user information. Then import them to a fresh copy of MySQL, after your database import

Comment: Note that system import should be AFTER your databases import

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysqldump (make sure you have the correct path to mysqldump):

## for a db named foo

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlX.X.X\bin\mysqldump -uroot -p foo > c:\path\foo.sql

## to dump a table named bar (in foo db)

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlX.X.X\bin\mysqldump -uroot -p foo bar > c:\path\foo-bar.sql

Answer (score 1):

normally i just copy data folder of mysql and then on another sytem replace this data folder, so its easy to move all of database

Comment: that way you can't upgrade your MySQL

Comment: i do, and its works, every time i format my sytem or if i uninstall wamp, wamp never delete mysql data dir, and www dir, and if i reinstall wamp, i just need to replace those data dir to get my all database and users back in mysql

Comment: i don't have any experience with change of mysql version

Comment: I'm sure you don't have experience when i see your way to import sql data.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSfrf.png)

Simply open http://localhost/phpmyadmin

For taking backup of all databases at once just click on Export. Here you go all your databases will be exported in a single Sql file.